# Sum of products of binomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I have been trying to check that two things are equal for a while now, Mathematica appears to say that they are but I can't for the life of me figure out how to show it (without just saying 'computer says yes'), does anybody know a 'nice' way to show the following expression is true?

$$\binom{v + w + d - 1}{d} = \sum_{a=0}^d \binom{v+a-1}{a} \binom{w + d - a - 1}{d-a}$$

Comment: It is Vandermonde-Chu identity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity

Comment: Thank you! However, I can't quite get it to give me what I have above - am I being dense? If I use that formula directly I get $\binom{v+w+d-2}{d}$ instead of a $v + w + d - 1$ on the top and through direct calculation that isn't equal to the sum on the right.

Comment: Ah! You should at first use reflection $\binom{n+a-1}{a}=(-1)^a\binom{-n}{a}$.

Comment: See also [Proving that ${x +y+n- 1 \choose n}= \sum_{k=0}^n{x+n-k-1 \choose n-k}{y+k-1 \choose k} $](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1867972) and some other posts from math.SE returned in this [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Ba%3D0%7D%5Ed%20%5Cbinom%7Bv%2Ba-1%7D%7Ba%7D%20%5Cbinom%7Bw%20%2B%20d%20-%20a%20-%201%7D%7Bd-a%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: The rhs is the coefficient of a Cauchy product of two binomial series, with exponent v and w resp, whence the identity.